# Hosting setup for a small application with security-sensitive data

Tags: windows, security, hosting

Not sure this is the right place to ask this but I'll give a shot.

I've been asked to implement a system about criminality data.
The data is security sensitive, in that it contains information about crimes
done by certain people in a violent context and delicate country.

Actually, the application will only have 4-5 users. Maybe a handful more later.
Nevertheless they are distributed and thus there should be access over a network.

They currently run a Windows server. I am highly experienced in linux environments,
my Windows server is quite dated.

What could be a good setup for such an application?
If I installed it at their own premises, which seems to be their preferred approach,
how would I go about providing access to the users?
Is a VPN a good approach? Any relevant info about how to do this with Windows?
Can I do it without having to host the app on the Internet?
Other suggestions?

Not sure if a standard web application hosted on a server somewhere on the Internet
could be sufficient.

I apologize if the question is too vague.
I am happy to try to provide more information if I can.
I am an experienced developer but not so much a system engineer.

Comment: Who asked you to do it?  Why did they ask you? Did you schmooze them into thinking you're a systems architect with the experience to pull this off?

Comment: Tom, I feel the first two questions are legitimate, the last is an unfounded insinuation of yours. I have been asked by a friend of mine who works there, and he told me "I know you are a developer, can you build a database application?" That's about it. It was my experience who actually prompted me to ask if data is security-sensitive. He didn't even know, it was his boss who said so.

Answer (score 7):

By your own admission you're not a system administrator nor security administrator. So if the data is as sensitive as you describe, hire someone who is experienced in the role. At the very least in a consultative/advisory role even if they don't do the actual work.

Based on TomTom's comment, I thought I should add a note about the possible legal implications of a failed implementation that make doing it yourself not worth the risk to yourself and/or the company asking you to do it.

Comment: +1 (I wish I could upvote more highly)

Comment: +1 too. The approach of asking for help wont help - I need to cook a 5 star menu, I am a bad cook, tell me what to do. If this is security sensitive you hire a professional. And pay. A lot - this is not "hosting on a cheap VPS or in the cloud" for obvious legal reasons.

Comment: I could design the system for OP, but it'd cost a serious chunk of money, both for time, and danger money.